# java convert map into a pojo when attribute names are different

Tags: java

Is it possible to convert map into a pojo when attribute names are different?

I am extracting raw input into a map to have the following data. Data can vary based on message type. For example:

for Message type = STANDARD

```
Map<String, Double> data = new HashMap<>();
data.set('TEMP', 18.33);
data.set('BTNUM', 123);
```

for Message type = NON_STANDARD

```
Map<String, Double> data = new HashMap<>();
data.set('GPSLAT', 12.33);
data.set('GPSLON', 42.33);
```

For each message type I have a Java model class

```
@Data
public class StandardMessage {
  private String longitude;
  private String latitude;
}

@Data
public class NonStandardMessage {
  private String temperature;
  private String btNumber;
}
```

Currenly I am mapping data to POJO class manually like below

```
StandardMessage sm = new StandardMessage();
sm.setLongitude(data.get('GPSLON'));

NonStandardMessage nsm = new NonStandardMessage();
nsm.setTemperature(data.get('TEMP'));
```

Is it possible to make above mapping generic? i.e setting object property without knowing name?

In Typescript we can achieve this easily by defining configuration like:

```
objectPropertyMapping = new Map();
objectPropertyMapping.set('GPSLAT', 'latitude');
objectPropertyMapping.set('GPSLON', 'longitude');

standardMessage = {};
data.forEach((value: boolean, key: string) => {
    standardMessage[ObjectPropertyMapping.get(key)] = data[key];
});
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zjn1kc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I know Java is a statically-typed language, just wondering is there a way to achieve this like typescript or we have to map manually all the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use [jackson-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind). It uses annotations for configuration.

Here are some example:

The entity class:

```
class MessageRequest {

    @JsonProperty("A")
    private String title;
    @JsonProperty("B")
    private String body;

    ... getters and setters ...
}
```

The main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> source = new HashMap<>();
    source.put("A", "This is the title");
    source.put("B", "Here is the body");


    MessageRequest req = objectMapper.convertValue(source, MessageRequest.class);

    System.out.println(req.getTitle());
    System.out.println(req.getBody());

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! never thought it would be as simple as this!!